# latest timestamp with other variables being same

Tags: sql, group-by, timestamp, max

Hi I have a SQL table which has 6 columns, one of which is timestamp. I need to know how to retain only the row that has the most recent timestamp.

example:

```
Product|Price|Product_id|Stock_code|supplier|timestamp
1      |375  |xxyyxx    |1234      |abcd    |2020-05-05
1      |372  |xxyyxx    |122       |abcd    |2020-05-04
1      |372  |xxyyxx    |122       |abcd    |2020-05-05
1      |375  |xxyyxx    |1234      |abcd    |2020-05-07
1      |375  |xxyyxx    |123       |abcd    |2020-05-07
2      |420  |xxyyyx    |1432      |bcda    |2020-05-07
2      |420  |xxyyyx    |1432      |bcda    |2020-05-06
2      |420  |xxyyyx    |1432      |bcda    |2020-05-13
```

What I need my table to look like is

```
Product|Price|Product_id|Stock_code|supplier|timestamp
1      |375  |xxyyxx    |1234      |abcd    |2020-05-07
1      |372  |xxyyxx    |122       |abcd    |2020-05-05
1      |375  |xxyyxx    |123       |abcd    |2020-05-07
2      |420  |xxyyyx    |1432      |bcda    |2020-05-13
```

So I want to return the latest timestamp when all other variables are equal to each other over the two or more timestamps.

What to write to arrive at this? I have tried too many things which are just not working. pLease help

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Looks like a basic GROUP BY.

Comment: I am very new to sql and struggling I have tried group by and order by but not working

Comment: I am using impala for writing sql queries

Comment: Wait. Do you mean you want to DELETE the older rows from the table?

Comment: I suppose your example is not sufficient. Or are really all values always the same per product except for the timestamp?

Comment: @Jarlh Your group by solution worked...i guess i was trying to complicate it way too much thanks.

Comment: Yeah the values arent always the same for each product so i need to retain those if they differ. I thin the group by has done the trick. Thanks guys.

Comment: The group by solution gives you one result row for each combination of product, price, product_id, stock_code, and supplier. Is this what you want? Don't you rather want just one result row per product?

Comment: Hi guys, me again; I have updated the query to give a better understanding of the example. Wht I need is to find the rows which have all same values except timestamp; and then return only the latest timestamp for those rows. Makes sense?

Comment: Doesn't my answer return exactly "_find the rows which have all same values except timestamp; and then return only the latest timestamp for those rows_"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`:

```
select Product, Price, Product_id, Stock_code, supplier, max(timestamp)
from tablename
group by Product, Price, Product_id, Stock_code, supplier
```